# How to exit (only) current activity if UncaughtExceptionHandler occurs?

Tags: android

I did a bit of coding to test out Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler for a specific use case (explained below).

Firstly, I have a `BaseActivity` implemented this way.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
                Log.e("CRASH_REPORT", "Activity crashed!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

By extending `BaseActivity`, any uncaught exception will end up being caught by the handler. `System.exit(0)` will terminate the **VM** belongs to the app.

Now, I created 2 activities with this hierarchy (both extending `BaseActivity`).

> ParentActivity -> SubActivity

In `ParentActivity`, I have only 1 button that will start `SubActivity` on clicked (code omitted).

In `SubActivity.onCreate(...)`, I purposely inject an exception to trigger `uncaughtException(...)`.

```
public class SubActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int crash = 1 / 0;
    }
}
```

When `SubActivity` executed, `uncaughtException(...)` triggered and the app stopped (obviously without the well known app stopped dialog).

What I want to know is whether its possible to just terminate the triggered Activity (`SubActivity` in this case) and app will roll-back (sort of) to its previous state (`ParentActivity`)?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just change `System.exit(0);` to `finish();` ?

Comment: @Buddy Tried that, and it hangs (ANR).

Comment: Ahh yeah... the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is called after the thread has already been terminated

Comment: @Buddy Yeah, you are right. I believe the only way to achieve this is to run each `Activity` in its own process. This is not recommended, though. So I am looking for an alternative. =)

Comment: @heike00 Or just wrap all your methods in try/catch blocks, and have them call into some central "mostly-uncaught exception" method.  :P

Comment: @Buddy That once came through my mind, and was quickly passed up for some silly reason: it makes the codes look awful. =p

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I believe there is **NO WAY** to return to previous `Activity` when `uncaughtException(...)` triggered as main thread has been stopped since.

Here, I will list down the ideas I have on "countermeasure" this issue.

### 1. Declare each `Activity` in different process (not recommended)

In the manifest file, add `android:process=dedicated_process_name` under each `activity` tag. Doing this will make each `Activity` running in its own process, thus ensuring crashing on 1 process does not affect another. This is not recommended, though.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ParentActivity"
    android:process="::parent_process" />
```

### 2. Force stop the app (`System.exit(code)`) and provide a callback where each `Activity` can define its own handling.

Create a `BaseActivity` with a `onCrashed(...)` callback.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
                Log.e("CRASH_REPORT", "Activity crashed!");
                onCrashed(thread, throwable);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onCrashed(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        // space for rent
    }
}
```

All `Activity` extending from `BaseActivity` can decide what they want to do on crash. An example is to schedule to start the application again.

```
public class SubActivity extends BaseActivity
    @Override
    protected void onCrashed(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ParentActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, pi);
    }
```

Alternatively, we can choose to implement uncaughtException(...) at `Application` level and `Application` will decide what to do next. (eg. restart current `Activity`)